Help solving a simple nonlinear system of equations
I need some help making sure Im solving a nonlinear system of equations correctly.
The system in question is the following:
$
\begin{cases}
x(y+1)(z+k) &= 0\\
\alpha(y+1)(z+k) &= 0\\
\alpha x (y+1) &= 0 \\
1 - \alpha x (z+k) &= 0
\end{cases}
$
The variables are $(x,y,z,\alpha)$
The way I solved it is by getting the solutions of the three first equations:
$\begin{cases}
x = 0, y = -1, z = -k\\
\alpha = 0, y = -1, z = -k\\
\alpha = 0, y = -1, x = 0
\end{cases}$
Then considering that the last equation can be rewritten as $1 = \alpha x (z+x)$
. I test the equation for every distinct possible solution, so:
$
\begin{cases}
x = 0 \implies 1 = \alpha \cdot 0 (z+k), \text{Not a solution}\\
\alpha = 0 \implies 1 = 0 \cdot x (z+k), \text{Not a solution}\\
z = -k \implies 1 = \alpha \cdot x (-k+k), \text{Not a solution}\\
y = -1 \implies 1 = \alpha \cdot x (z+k), \text{Possible solution?}
\end{cases}
$
So the solution to the system would be any set of values $(x,-1,z,\alpha)$ as long as $x,z,\alpha$ verify that $1-\alpha x (z+k)$ ?
That means that there are infinite possible solutions to the system right? Is the method I used correct or I missed something? Also since the number of equations and variables are the same, the system is determined so shouldn't there be a single solution for the system?
Thanks!

A shortcut to this: If $y\neq 1$, then the factor of $y+1$ can be eliminated from the first three equations. But then $\alpha x(z+k)=0$ (using any of those three reduced equations) and thus the last equation would be $1-0=0$ which is not possible. So $y=-1$ is required, and the problem reduces to solving the last equation.

The third equation $\alpha x (y+1) = 0$ yields $y+1=0$,
since $\alpha x\neq 0$ by the last equation. For $y=-1$ the system reduces to the last equation, namely to
$$
z=\frac{1}{\alpha x}-k.
$$
Here $x$ and $\alpha$ are arbitrary, except for the requirement, that they are nonzero.
